# Paypal's IPN notification - "recurring_payment_skipped" vs "recurring_payment_failed"

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, payment

I set up a recurring payment with paypal within my website.

So if customer's balance is empty the value of "**txn_type**" will be "**recurring_payment_skipped**".

**After 3 failed  attempts**,  the value of "**txn_type**" will be "**recurring_payment_suspended_due_to_max_failed_payment**" and in this case   the related recurring payment profile has been suspended.

So, can you explain to me the difference between  **recurring_payment_skipped** and **recurring_payment_failed** ? and when we have exactly  **txn_type =  recurring_payment_failed ?**

Comment: I never see recurring_payment_failed.  I only ever see skipped.

Comment: It exist (recurring_payment_failed ). Please see the following link  [IPN transaction types](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables#id08CTB0S055Z)

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I am telling you in my 8+ years of working with recurring payments profiles I've never seen a "failed".  Only "skipped".

Comment: thank you very much for your response. Please, is there a tool to simulate a skipped transaction ?

Comment: You'd have to build your own simulator for that.  Just build an HTML form that has the same field names you'd expect to get from PayPal on that type of an IPN and POST it directly to your IPN listener.  Of course, keep in mind it won't validate with PayPal when you test that way.

Comment: You could use a rest client in your browser to set the form values and POST your data to your IPN listener. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/restclient/ on Fireforx or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo on Chrome.